# Angular project using express generator

Tags: angularjs, express

I have created a project using express generator. Then I installed bower to get bootstrap and angular. I am using express for REST web services. I have defined angular routes too. I can get too my index page but my angular routes are not working.

**app.js**

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var fs = require('fs');

//load all models defined in .js files under models dir
fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/models').forEach(function(filename){
  if(~filename.indexOf('.js')) require(__dirname + '/models/'+ filename);
})

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hjs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('less-middleware')(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/bower_components', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'bower_components')));
//app.use('/bower_components',  express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mongo');
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

**Index.js (express REST)**

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.model('donuts',{id:String, type:String, name:String});
//mongoose.model('users', {firstname: String, lastName: String, email: String});
//all models are now loaded from app.js file
router.get('/userlist', function(req, res){
  mongoose.model('users').find(function(err, users){
    res.send(users);
  });
});

router.get('/userlist/:userId', function(req, res){
  mongoose.model('users').find({_id: req.params.userId},function(err, users){
    res.send(users)
  });
});

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); // load our public/index.html file
});

module.exports = router;
```

**MainModule.js (Angular Module and Route)**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('LoginRegisterApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

    $routeProvider.when('/login',{
        templateUrl: 'views/login',
        controller: 'LoginController'
    });
}]);
```

**LoginCtrl.js (Angular Controller)**

```js
myApp.controller('LoginController',['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.hello = "Helloo world Sunil";
}]);
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app='LoginRegisterApp'>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>index</title>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css"> <!-- custom styles -->

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- ANGULAR CUSTOM -->
    <script src="MainModule.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/controllers/LoginCtrl.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="LoginController">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="/login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<!-- ANGULAR DYNAMIC CONTENT -->
{{hello}}
<div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It should be noted that Bower isn't currently being supported - smarter to switch to npm for everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

Replace the code in app.js file and comment out the old code for setting the engine.

As well as keep the index.html file in public directory and add the following code in app.js file :

app.use(express.static("./public"));

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile("./public/index.html");
});
```